# update json file using servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

In a java web app, i want to update the json file with the data which is received at server.
The json file already  exists in **Web Pages\json\cards.json**  as:

```
[
{
   "name": "Dhruvam Gupta",
   "job_title":"Android Developer",
   "email":"dhruvamprashant@gmail.com",
   "phone":"9839262655"
}
]
```

First i **read the JsonArray** from cards.json as follows which is **successfully** done because
**System.out.println(array)** gives the previous and appended data as:

```
[
{"name":"Dhruvam Gupta","job_title":"Android Developer","email":"dhruvamprashant@gmail.com","phone":"9839262655"},
{"email":"gabor.orosz@me.com","phone":"+36 30 610 6976","name":"Orosz Gábor","job_title":"Android Developer"}]
```

I have read the data as:

```
ServletContext context  = getServletContext();

    InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/json/cards.json");
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    JsonReader jsr = new JsonReader(isr);
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement element = parser.parse(jsr);
    JsonArray array = element.getAsJsonArray();

    JsonElement ele = parser.parse(card);

    array.add(ele);
    System.out.println(array);
```

But when i try to write the **array** to json file then the exception is thrown as: **\json\cards.json (The system cannot find the path specified)**.

```
 try {

        FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(new File("/json/cards.json"));

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fw));

        bw.write(array.getAsString());

        bw.close();

        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

So i want to know how can i update the data successfully.
I think the problem is in opening **OutputStream** from servlet to cards.json file.

Plz help me to rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444944/how-to-do-file-i-o-with-a-servlet-running-on-tomcat), including the linked tutorial and blogpost.

Second, the path in `context.getResourceAsStream("/json/cards.json")` is relative to the deployment directory of your web application **OR** classpath (i.e. it is possible to load the resources from e.g. JAR files in `WEB-INF/lib` this way). But `new File("/json/cards.json")` uses absolute path on your file system, i.e. the paths are not the same.